# How do I add another page in my UIPageViewController.swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new to programming in Xcode and I was wondering how I can add a new page to my UIPageViewController? I followed a youtube tutorial in order to achieve this. In the IOS Simulator it works fine but I just want to add another page, I have a storyboard with the ID "third" that's the page I would like to add, I have tried adding the third storyboard as a new viewController, add some code in the viewControllerAfter section but the code ends up breaking can anybody help me out?

```
 import UIKit

class PageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    lazy var orderedviewControllers: [UIViewController] = {
        return [self.newVc(viewController: "first"),
                self.newVc(viewController: "second")]
    }()

    var pageControl = UIPageControl()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.dataSource = self
        if let firstViewController = orderedviewControllers.first {
            setViewControllers([firstViewController],
                               direction: .forward,
                               animated: true,
                               completion: nil)
        }

        self.delegate = self
        configurePageControl()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func configurePageControl() {
        pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY - 50, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50))
        pageControl.numberOfPages = orderedviewControllers.count
        pageControl.currentPage = 0
        pageControl.tintColor = UIColor.black
        pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white
        pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black
        self.view.addSubview(pageControl)
    }
    func newVc(viewController: String) -> UIViewController {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewController)
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedviewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
            return nil
        }

        let previousIndex  = viewControllerIndex - 1

        guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
            return orderedviewControllers.last
        }
        guard orderedviewControllers.count > previousIndex else {
            return nil
        }
        return orderedviewControllers[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
         guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedviewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
                   return nil
               }

               let nextIndex  = viewControllerIndex + 1

        guard orderedviewControllers.count != nextIndex else {
                return orderedviewControllers.first

               }
               guard orderedviewControllers.count > nextIndex else {
                   return nil
               }

               return orderedviewControllers[nextIndex]
                   }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        let pageContentViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers![0]
        self.pageControl.currentPage = orderedviewControllers.index(of: pageContentViewController)!

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code to set up your page controller, add new view controllers in page array. This is not done using storyboard but may be of additional help

```
class PageController: UIViewController {

var pages = [UIViewController]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: .none)
    view.backgroundColor = .clear
    pageViewController.dataSource = self
    pageViewController.delegate = self

    let initialPage = 0
    let page1 = CustomController1()
    let page2 = CustomController2()
    let page3 = CustomController3()

    // add the individual viewControllers to the pageViewController
    self.pages.append(page1)
    self.pages.append(page2)
    self.pages.append(page3)

    let pageControllerView = pageViewController.view
    view.addSubview(pageControllerView!)
    addChild(pageViewController)


    let dictionary: [String: UIView] = ["pageControllerView": pageControllerView!]
    var vflString = "H:|-0-[pageControllerView]-0-|"
    var vflConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: vflString, options: [], metrics: nil, views: dictionary)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(vflConstraints)

    vflString = "V:|-[pageControllerView]-|"
    vflConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: vflString, options: [], metrics: nil, views: dictionary)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(vflConstraints)


// EDIT:

// Add new view controller on tapping a a button
let button = UIButton(frame: .zero)
    button.setTitle("This is a button", for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    page1.view.addSubview(button)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addPage), for: .touchUpInside)

    var vflString = "V:|-100-[button(50)]"
    var vflConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: vflString,
                                                        options: [],
                                                        metrics: nil,
                                                        views: ["button": button])

    page1.view.addConstraints(vflConstraints)

    vflString = "H:|-100-[button(50)]"
    vflConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: vflString,
                                                    options: [],
                                                    metrics: nil,
                                                    views: ["button": button])
    page1.view.addConstraints(vflConstraints)

    pageViewController.setViewControllers([pages[initialPage]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
@objc private func addPage() {
    let page2 = UIViewController()
    page2.view.backgroundColor = .brown
    pages.append(page2)
}
}

extension PageController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {



func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if let viewControllerIndex = self.pages.firstIndex(of: viewController) {
        if viewControllerIndex == 0 {
            // wrap to last page in array
            return self.pages.last
        } else {
            // go to previous page in array
            return self.pages[viewControllerIndex - 1]
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if let viewControllerIndex = self.pages.firstIndex(of: viewController) {
        if viewControllerIndex < self.pages.count - 1 {
            // go to next page in array
            return self.pages[viewControllerIndex + 1]
        } else {
            // wrap to first page in array
            return self.pages.first
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {

    // set the pageControl.currentPage to the index of the current viewController in pages
    if let viewControllers = pageViewController.viewControllers {
        if let viewControllerIndex = self.pages.firstIndex(of: viewControllers[0]) {
            self.pageControl.currentPage = viewControllerIndex
        }
    }
}

// The number of items reflected in the page indicator.
func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {

}

// The selected item reflected in the page indicator.
func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return 1
}
}
```

Comment: do you have any idea how to add another page using the code I posted above, this is the tutorial I followed if you need a reference https://www.seemuapps.com/page-view-controller-tutorial-with-page-dots

Comment: Added a button in page1 to add new controller

Comment: @Anthony did the answer help you?